# Returning the max record count by grouping in linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, dataset

I'm very new to linq and I'm trying to come up with a linq query against a dataset that will return a max count value based on grouping records.

The linq query that I have so far is

```
  Dim sales = From soldData In SDOSoldDataTable.AsEnumerable
        Where (soldData.Field(Of DateTime)("sold_date") >= lastMonthStartDate _
        And soldData.Field(Of DateTime)("sold_date") <= lastMonthEndDate) _
        Group soldData By username = soldData.Field(Of String)("user_name") _
        Into Group _
        Select _
           username, _
           numSales = Group.Count()
```

This query gives me the number of sales per salesperson(username) during the last month.  I now want to the return the name of the salesperson who had the most sales during the last month.  I'm guessing it's some type of an Aggregate query using Max() against sales, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks,
omar

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LargestSale = (From sale In sales
                    Order By sale.numSales Descending
                    Select sale).First()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get a different against 'sales'

"Expression of type 'Object' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider."

I think I'm importing the correct libraries:
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Data.DataTableExtensions
Imports System.Data.Linq

Comment: I just googled the error, some results mention turn "Option Infer" On.  I turned it on, but no difference.  Also, I'm working in NET 4.0 it that makes a difference.